# Android Viewpager display wrong data on first load

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

/**i'm using android.support.v4.view.ViewPager with tabhost for show a tab data, i have 3 tab 
when first time it is load 1st tab is load 3rd tab data ...3rd tab is load 1st tab data .and 2nd tab is correctly loads own data

My Code For viewpager and tabhost is Thx in Advance **/

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private String[] tabsTitles = {"SELL", "RENT", "PROJECT"};

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabsTitles.length);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        final TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabsTitles.length; i++) {
            String tabName = tabsTitles[i];
            TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName);
            spec.setContent(R.id.fakeTabContent);
            spec.setIndicator(tabName);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
        }
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tabsTitles.length; i++) {
                    if (tabId.equals(tabsTitles[i])) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Give ME Answer Friends ...Help Me

Comment: always it is loading a wrong items?

Comment: yes @Fahim 1st tab is load 3rd tab layout and 3rd tab is loading 1st tab layout

Comment: can you share the tabpageradapter code

Comment: how? dont forget to add the answer for other users

Comment: i had done mistake in tab pager adapter classs

Comment: /*Now Its Works*/               public Fragment getItem(int index) {

  switch (index % 3) {
  case 2:
   // Top Rated fragment activity
   return new ProjectFragment();
  case 1:
   // Games fragment activity
   return new RentFragment();
  case 0:
   // Movies fragment activity
   return new SellFragment();
  }

  return null;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a issue in the adapter code

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) { 
    switch (index % 3) {
     case 2: // Top Rated fragment activity return
     new ProjectFragment(); 
    case 1: // Games fragment activity 
    return new RentFragment(); 
    case 0: // Movies fragment activity
     return new SellFragment();
     } return null; 
    }
```

Comment: @Tufan added your answer from comment to answer section for other users who refer this