# View Pager is empty only at first time

Tags: android

I have a fragment that contains recycle view and on every item press another fragment is shown that holding a view pager that shows fragment on every swipe. when I first enter to the fragment after pressing the recycle view item the pager is not visible.
on second time and the rest of the times the data is shown as expected.

code:

main fragment holds view pager:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lineItems"
            style="@style/TitleTextView"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/CardTablepager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

content fragment (view pager swipes this fragment) :

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/poMainlayout">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/CardViewStyle"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/poLineItemsTable"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I read few posts with no help: [Android Viewpager display wrong data on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912454/android-viewpager-display-wrong-data-on-first-load)

I also tried to invalidate the adapter from the main fragment with no help:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();          

    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: you dont have to put `Recyclerview` inside `ScrollView` it implements `ScrollingView` & `NestedScrollingChild`

Comment: I wanted to create recycle view with horizontal and vertical scroll, not the issue so I've updated the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just notify your adapter onCreateView not onViewCreated

```
@Override
public void onCreateView(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();          

}
```

Comment: where did you define your viewpager?.if it is possible put your entire fragment

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  the viewpager view is not yet inflate here so it won't work.

Comment: Just let me know about your first fragment and where did you define your viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Try below changes to your viewpager,

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/CardTablepager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="600dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

And for `RecyclerView` set following properties:

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Nice try, but still the same behavior.